# how to disconnect a windows remote directory?

Tags: windows, networking, smb

I'm coding a program to monitor a remote directory,
and I use the windows API: WNetAddConnection. 
I use it to map remote directory to Z: by use a specified user/password.

After I put this program to the working environment,
someone use explorer location "\192.168.X.X\somedir" to login the same directory I monitored,
and it makes my program cannot connect to this directory,
so I have to ask this people not to do this thing, but I cannot force them not to.

So I want to know if there is a way to disconnect all the other connection,
or provent them do this thing,
do anyone knows how?

By the way, I'm not a expert in windows, 
I don't know the detail of windows network (or what this bug really means),
can anyone tell me where is the documentation for windows network?

Comment: I don't know why, when the people use explorer and put location:"\192.168.X.X\somedir"
and user their user/pwd , my program will fail to connect the same shared dir..

Comment: That's a Microsoft limitation.  One Windows client accessing shares on one Windows server has to use the same username and password for all the shares it's accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly option:

You could parse the output of "net use" and then disconnect the connections you don't like using "net use /d"

([WNetCancelConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385427(VS.85).aspx) seems to be the API that net use /d uses)

Answer (score 1):

```
WNetCancelConnection2
```

But it's not the friendliest thing to do to people.

Comment: we are developing a program only used in our factory, and the users are workers...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the API but net session /delete will disconnect all open session to a share.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this  follow the step:
1,run the order to delete all the net user and the passwd ,the order is :
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL keymgr.dll 
2,delete all the information of the net user in the memory use the order:
`net use * /delete /y`
or you can create one bat file whit the follow information:

```
@echo off
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL keymgr.dll
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y

net use
net use
net use

net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
net use * /delete /y
```